# Is there a way to create a JFrame in an online compiler?

Tags: java, swing, ide, jframe

I have used NetBeans IDE 8.2 for a while to create Java programs, and have had no trouble with it. I was trying to find an online compiler that will allow me to create a JFrame, but I usually get the error saying

```
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
```

I have tried several different online compilers, as well as researching the X11 DISPLAY, but I haven't found anything useful.

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static JFrame frame;
    public static Canvas canvas;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createDisplay("Display", 500, 500);
    }

    public static void createDisplay(String title, int w, int h) {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(w, h);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.setSize(w, h);
        canvas.setFocusable(false);

        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.pack();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to set the X11 DISPLAY variable to make it work on an online compiler?

Comment: I'm not aware of any online-compiler which lets you create a window. Fiddling with X11 won't help you. These web services are probably headless. And even if they had X installed you wouldn't be able to see the window in your browser. The online compiler had to explicitly implement something to send and show X windows in your browser.

Comment: The server running the compiler is most likely a headless linux system, so it can't show a Swing component even if you run the code locally. But in your case, the web page where you run your code just returns the console content in a HTML page. It doesn't "share" the server screen with you where you could see the JFrame (if the server was capable of doing that).

Comment: Couldn't you just install the JDK locally, maybe in an VM?

Comment: Why do you want to use a local NetBeans but a remote (online) compiler?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? While technically this is doable since X11 supports remote displays, it'd be *really* annoying.

Answer (score 9):

[Repl.it](https://repl.it) allows you to create JFrames
[See here](https://repl.it/@BenjaminUrquhar/AnotherUnknownFlatassembler)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run Java in **headless mode**:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true ...
```

Use cases: unit testing, server side graphics operations.

You can also set it programmatically (must be set before performing any AWT calls that require a display):

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

See: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html